# How Could I use array to show match Imageview?

Tags: android, arrays, imageview

I get some data like this : 
{201,501,301,404,211}

I use ',' to split

```
      String[] messages = split(",");
```

so I get 201 501 301 404 211 , now I just only need three values : 201 501 301

```
      messages[0];  //201
      messages[1];  //501
      messages[2];  //301
```

but , I have nine icon , and only three icon will show base on messages[0] ~ messages[2]

here is my xml :

```
               <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ig_p1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/precaution_top"
                    android:src="@mipmap/icon_101" />
               <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ig_p2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/precaution_top"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ig_precaution_1"
                    android:src="@mipmap/icon_403" />
               <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ig_p3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/precaution_top"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ig_precaution_2"
                    android:src="@mipmap/icon_401" />
```

according to my xml , there are only three ImageView will show , I want to show array[0] ~ array[2] to match imageView.

```
  ImageView p1,p2,p3;
  p1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ig_p1);
  p2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ig_p2);
  p3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ig_p3);
```

please help me , Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set icons dynamically.

Create a function and call 3 times.

ig_p1ImageView, ig_p2ImageView, and ig_p3ImageView are image views that you use in Java side with findViewById().

```
void setIcon(String iconName, ImageView imageView ) {
    String fileName = "icon_" + iconName
    int iconResId = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "mipmap", getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(iconResId);
}

setIcon(messages[0], ig_p1ImageView );
setIcon(messages[1], ig_p2ImageView );
setIcon(messages[2], ig_p3ImageView );
```

Comment: so if I want three ImageView , 
String fileName1 =  "icon_" + messages[0] , String fileName2 =  "icon_" + messages[1] , String fileName3 =  "icon_" + messages[2] ?

Comment: I created the function for you.